# image appears transparent when imported into Photoshop

Tags: rendering, image

When I do a render of a background, in Blender it seems 100% with its opacity, but when I import it into Photoshop I can see its transparent, the background is noticeable. What's causing this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see/understand the issue. Can you explain more? The 2 images look the same to me. Also when you say "seems 100%", have you actually checked in Blender that the alpha channel is really 100%?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake the file was saved as RGBA instead of RGB, so you if you have save as RGBA (alpha) it comes into PS with semi transparent background.